# C# ASP.NET Core - Data.Annotations - Regex for specific email

Tags: c#, .net, regex, data-annotations

How to implement this regex `\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@(live\.wcs\.ac\.uk)\b` to a regular expression check via data annotations in ASP.NET core.

```
[Required]    
[RegularExpression(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@(live\.wcs\.ac\.uk)\b)]    
public string Email {get; set; }
```

This is how I'm trying to set it as I want there to be @live.wcs.ac.uk as a validation check but my IDE does not like the input I'm trying above.

Any help with a quick explaination of how to set up the annotation properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex in C# should be declared as a `string` object, i.e.:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@(live\.wcs\.ac\.uk)\b")]
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an error message to the annotation in the same line? For example something to say "Email must contain @live.wcs.ac.uk" ....

Comment: @BaldyBonito, yes, simply use `ErrorMessage"` property of the attribute.

Comment: As simple as this then? [RegularExpression(@"\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@(live\.wcs\.ac\.uk)\b", ErrorMessage = "Email address must be a student email.")]

Comment: @BaldyBonito, yep

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better if you use:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "your error message here")]
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute?view=net-5.0)

Comment: This is a general annotation you can set on an email address field. The question is about a regular expression.